# How can I shift from using namespace std to "std_lib_facilities.h" in ST3, OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, header-files

I've tried this solution:

Downloaded the correct .h file and put it in the folder on my desktop where I store all my .cpp files.

This didn't work.

I'm very new to working with computers in the capacity of a programmer, so I'm very ignorant. I'm sure there is a very simple answer to this that requires a basic level of knowing your way around a computer, or the ST3 settings (neither of which I have).

Help would be much appreciated.